# How to convert a binary number into integer via UDP receive in python

Tags: python, pi-2, matlab

I have sent a number from Matlab via UDP using the commands below:

```
u=udp('192.168.137.239',5004) ;create UDP object
u.OutputBufferSize = 1000;
fopen(u)
fwrite(u,200,'int' ) ; write number 200
```

but when I receive this number on the Raspberry in python via UDP, it is not displayed correctly (it display 3355443200L), I use `unpack` to convert as in the following code:

```
import sys, struct
from socket import*
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pickle

SIZE = 65535

hostName = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')

mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
mySocket.bind((hostName,5004))

repeat = True


while repeat:
    (data, addr)=mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    data1 = struct.unpack('I', data)
    print " received meassage:",data1
```

Please tell me how to convert binary from Matlab into integer in python.

Answer (score 2):

`3355443200L` is in fact `C8000000` in hex format, which is the number 200 padded by three extra zero bytes. This happens because UDP data is transmitted in [Network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking), while `fwrite` writes data in the computer's natural order (little endian on Intel computers).

You will need to swap the bytes manually before sending them from Matlab, using [`swapbytes`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html):

```
fwrite(u,swapbytes(int32(200)),'int'); Write integer number 200
```

Another option is to change the transmission byteorder using `u.ByteOrder = 'littleEndian'`, but I don't have Matlab to test how that works.